# Optimising Firestore costs for time series data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have been using Postgres to store time-series sensor data but I am weighing the cost of using Firestore cause I prefer the serverless nature of Firestore. My only concern is the cost of Firestore because I am paying for every read. I want to be able to display this sensor information on my web app. Now, I am taking data every 10 seconds and theres over 400+ sensor points (400 columns per row in my postgres table)

Currently, if a user queries for a week's work of data that's about 60,000 rows of data, but I optimise it by just taking every nth value to "feather" the data. So by taking every 20th row for example, I have reduced the return of the data to 3000 rows which is manageable and still the chart shows a clear trend.

I want to be able to do this in Firestore to save costs, because if a user queries for a week's data, I am paying for 60000 document reads which I can't display all those data points on the web app anyway. I have tried searching for ways to query firestore to take the Nth row of data, but haven't found any concrete solutions.

Does anybody have any recommendation how I can optimise my Firestore costs for time series data or perhaps any other cheap serverless methods to manage this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't offer any way to "feather" data from queries, as you say.  What you could do instead is put an integer in each document that describes its "Nth" value, then query for only those "N" that you want.

Comment: But putting an integer that describes each Nth values requires me to track the running number on the script that uploads data to Firestore, but surely this introduces some complications and inflexibility if the running number is somehow messed up due to data loss or if it needs to be reuploaded

Comment: I'm sure those hiccups can be ignored if infrequent or worked around. I can think of no other option. I believe you will have to solve this on the client.

Comment: Ok fair. Thank's for the advice! :)